# Result for Regression not correct

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, regression

I'm a beginner in machine learning (ML) and can't figure out why my regression is incorrect or not plotting correctly. This is what I have currently and most is taken from previous examples of a book which I'm working with. Would be nice if somebody could also explain where the formula for the cost function comes from.

```
import time
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def read_csv(filepath, bucket=7):

    days_in_year = 365

    freq = {}
    for period in range(0, int(days_in_year / bucket)):
        freq[period] = 0

    with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        csvreader.__next__()
        for row in csvreader:
            if row[0] == '':
                continue
            t = time.strptime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y")
            if t.tm_year == 2014 and t.tm_yday < (days_in_year-1):
                freq[int(t.tm_yday / bucket)] += 1
    print("finished reading input")
    return freq


freq = read_csv("311_data.csv")

x_dataset = list(freq.keys())
y_dataset = list(freq.values())

print(x_dataset)
print(y_dataset)


def normalize(data):
    y = np.empty(len(data))
    count = 0
    for x in data:
        y[count] = (x-min(data))/(max(data)-min(data))
        count += 1
    return y


x_dataset = normalize(x_dataset)
y_dataset = normalize(y_dataset)

(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(x_dataset, y_dataset, train_size=0.7, test_size=0.3)

learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 40
num_coeffs = 9
reg_lambda = 0.

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


def model(X, w):
    terms = []
    for i in range(num_coeffs):
        term = tf.multiply(w[i], tf.pow(X, i))
        terms.append(term)
    return tf.add_n(terms)


w = tf.Variable([0.] * num_coeffs, name="parameters")
y_model = model(X, w)

cost = tf.div(tf.add(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y-y_model)), tf.multiply(reg_lambda, tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(w)))),
          2*x_train.size)

train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for reg_lambda in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y: y_train})
    final_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_test, Y: y_test})
    print('reg lambda ', reg_lambda)
    print('final cost ', final_cost)

w_val = sess.run(w)
print(w_val)
sess.close()

plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)
y_learned = 0

for i in range(num_coeffs):
    y_learned += w_val[i] * np.power(x_train, i)

plt.plot(x_train, y_learned, 'r')
plt.show()
```

And that is my result when plotting:

[image: plotting result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're getting the right X,Y coordinates, you're just plotting them out of order. Try `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot` to get just points instead of lines, to verify this. If you still want lines, you can pair-wise sort in the following way:

```
points = zip(x_train, y_learned)
points = sorted(points, key=lambda p: p[0])
x_plot, y_plot = zip(*points)
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot, 'r')
```